# What HTFS means?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, operating-systems

When I start my computer I get error file HTFS. What HTFS file means and how can I solve this problem. I have Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Are you certain the error is HTFS and not NTFS? Could you provide the complete error message?

Comment: No is not NTFS.

Comment: And every time is trying to check my disk.

Comment: From what I can find HTFS is a journaling file system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Throughput_File_System. The wiki page is a rough description so basically you have a disk error that Windows is trying to fix.

Comment: CHECKING FILE SYSTEM....THE FILE NAME IS HTFS. IT IS RECOMMENDED THAT YOU DO THE CHECKING OF THE DISK. IF YOU WANT TO CANCEL PRESS ANY KEY.

Comment: http://www.progtalk.com/viewarticle.aspx?articleid=557

Comment: that's not a windows message but rather SCO Unix.

Comment: i thought htfs wasnt supported by windows? did you have this hard drive in another computer?

Comment: @bmargulies: Other than the "HTFS" bit, it's exactly like the message printed by Windows `chkdsk`.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is allow Windows to perform the disk scan.  It could take quite some time to complete.  This type of error happens when the computer suffers a power-loss or after a blue-screen error.  It's also possible that the hard drive itself is going bad.